# AngularJS - Date input and Number input validation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

I have two basic input fields in my website (one input date and one input number):

-For the date input I'm able to set a minimum and maximum when the user selects the date from the calendar but when the date is written manually those minimum and maximum are not respected. I would like to know how can I solve this issue so when the user types the date the minimum and maximum are respected.

-For the number input, it only has to accept positive values. In addition, if the value typed is 0 I would like to show an error message or put a red frame in the input field.

Answer (score 0):

- For first question you can put a function on ng-change and pass inside of it model and validate in in your controller Other way you
  can write a custom validator directive but i doubt there is real need
  for that.

  ```
      <input type="text" 
        datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="myDate" 
        ng-change="checkDate(myDate)/>
  ```

and inside controller

```
$scope.checkDate(date) {
  if(date < new Date()) {
    $scope.dateError = true
  }
}
```

and in your view

```
<p ng-show="$scope.dateError">
  Please enter date bigger then today
</p>
```

- there is a min attribute that lets you set a minimum accepted value in your case it should be 1

To show error you can use a something like that

```
<p ng-show="yourFormName.fieldName.$invalid">
  Please enter something else
</p>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Note that this means your input must absolutely within a form tag, angular can't do validation on a input not in a form tag.

Comment: Yes that is correct thanks for adding, that i also suggest to add debounce to date validation so validation wont get fired everytime

Comment: Thank you, that would work. The thing is that I'm using an input type date instead of text. I know it doesn't work for Firefox or Explorer but that's what I need now for my website.

Comment: I suggest not to use input type date, it has a quite annoying bug in chromium and if I remember correctly firefox it will add one more  datepicker button inside of input field. If you really must use input type date you can still compare dates just make sure you comparing date object against date object. 

Also, there is a perfect library for working with dates called moment.js 

It probably has all the compartment rules you may ever need for dates.

Hope this is helpfull

Answer (score 0):

check below code..

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Number:
    <input type="number" name="input" ng-model="example.value"
           min="0" max="99" required>
 </label>
  <div role="alert">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
      Required!</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.number">
      Not valid number!</span>
  </div>

<label>Email Address:
    <input type="email" name="txtemail" ng-model="example.email"
            required>
 </label>
  <div role="alert">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.txtemail.$error.required">
      Required!</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.txtemail.$error.email">
      Not valid number!</span>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Thank you, that will be useful for future validations.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the answer for your second question.

- *For the number input, it only has to accept positive values. In addition, if the value typed is 0 I would like tho show an error message or put a red frame in the input field.*

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.showError = function(data){
$scope.isError=false;
if(data==0)
$scope.isError=true;
}
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input type="number" min="0" ng-change="showError(inputValue)" ng-model="inputValue"></input>
<p ng-show="isError" style="color:red">Error msg - you typed Zero</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works for me. I was thinking that for my website I would like to do the validation if the input number when the user clicks the save button and then display an alert message preventing the user to save the information if the input number is equals to 0